# Apply divide formula to entire column in macro on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to apply this formula not only to B2 cell but the entire B column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target = [B2] Then
    Dim amount As Long
    amount = [B2]

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Value = amount / (100000000)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Any kind of help will very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rngCol As Range

  'Get the range from the table column header
  Set rngCol = Me.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns("Col2").DataBodyRange

  'EDIT: alternative for multiple contiguous columns
  Set rngCol = Me.Range("myTable[Col2]:myTable[Col4]")

  'any changes in the monitored column?
  Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, rngCol)

  If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<< got some changes in ColB
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each c In rng.Cells
          If IsNumeric(c.Value) Then 
              'Update: only apply to values >1
              If c.Value > 1 Then c.Value = c.Value / 100000000
          End If
      Next c
      Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If

End Sub
```

(edited to show use of Table/ListObject)

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a dynamic table, maybe I can use this header to apply the macro? The code works!

Comment: Yes you can adjust the Intersect line to use a structured table reference.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to do it? I added IfNumeric conditional to avoid bad executions but I didn't know how to use table column to limit the target range.

Thanks again Tim.

Comment: Thank. I entered the name of my table but the execution of code shows "Subscript out of range (Error 9)".

Comment: Should work if your table and column names (you need to adjust both of those) are correct - tested on my side.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I was using another column name. Changed this in Macro code and worked like a charm!!

Comment: Tim, for add more columns to the macro what method do you recommend? I'm trying to use union but i dont know what would be the best solution in that case.

Comment: Yep. The columns are in range "Col2:Col4"

Comment: See edit above and https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e

Comment: Yes, I know that but I don't know how to select this in macro (I really don't know nothing on VBA). The behaviour it's the last one that you share with me, I want to apply this code to three columns not only one.

.ListColumns("Col2:Col4") didn't work at all.

Comment: OK Tim, you got it!! Thanks again mate!

Comment: Hey Tim. Sometimes when I use this macro I see that numbers got 8 extra decimals. For example "0,00000350" turns into "0,0000000000000350".

Maybe the code can be improved to avoid that thing?

Thanks.

Comment: How would the code know not to perform the division?

Comment: Maybe the division can be done only when user input numbers on cells?

Comment: 0,00000350 is a number...   You could modify the code such that it ignores any cell valuet < 1 for example.  I'm not sure what range the input numbers would typically be in, but you get the idea.  You might want to re-think this whole idea though: it would be best to leave the user's input as-is, and calculate the other value somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe there is a way to read decimals or apply the division only in integer numbers?